wpf - cannot change ui color dynamically
I want to be able to change the background color of my tool window (it is a VSIX, not an App)
so I need to programatically have PanelBackground point to either PanelBackgroundLight or PanelBackgroundDark
this is the style sheet I use (dropped the header)
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PanelBackgroundLight" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PanelBackgroundDark" Color="#FF000000"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PanelBackground" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource PanelBackgroundLight}, Path=Color}"/>

I use this function to trigger the update the UI, no matter what I try, the background color does not change
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
  public void UpdateColors()
  {
     Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
     {
         ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

         // this changes colors in the resource dictionary
         var themeChanger = new ThemeChanger();
         themeChanger.UpdateColors();

         // this is supposed to force the UI to refresh
         InvalidateVisual();
         Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
         Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, DesiredSize.Width, DesiredSize.Height));
         UpdateLayout();
     });
  }
...

this is the class I created for my themes
public class ThemeChanger
{
    private readonly ResourceDictionary _resourceDictionary;

    public ThemeChanger()
    {
        _resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary
        {
            Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/LSPConector2019;component/wpf/styles/Styles.xaml")
        };
    }

    public void UpdateColors()
    {
        var darkBrush = ((SolidColorBrush)_resourceDictionary["PanelBackgroundDark"]);
        _resourceDictionary["PanelBackground"] = new SolidColorBrush(darkBrush.Color);
    }
}

the main user control xaml
<UserControl x:Class="MyNameSpace.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:vsshell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0"
             xmlns:vsplatformui="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.ToolWindowBackgroundKey}}"
             Foreground="Black"
             Name="MyToolWindow"
             d:DesignWidth ="1000"
             d:DesignHeight="500">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyNamespace;component/wpf/styles/Styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

  <!-- also tried DynamicResource  -->
  <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Background="{StaticResource PanelBackground}">
  ...

any help appreciated

It is unclear how this is supposed to work. Your ThemeChanger creates a private ResourceDictionary that is not used by your application. You probably wanted to change UserControl.Resources and use DynamicResource.

Besides that, it seems totally redundant to call ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread() in a Dispatcher.Invoke Action. Also calling InvalidateVisual, Measure, Arrange and UpdateLayout in sequence is never necessary.

@Clemens, yes it does, check the template at the bottom

What does what? Which template?

@Mustafa Mutasim, I tried your code but only my dictionary has the color I am looking for, the merge dictionary dont have my color definition. Also trying to replace colors instead of brushes give me the same result, the UI is not updated

@pf12345678910, Yes it will not work, I asked you before if you want the version of WPF I can post my answer if it matches your requirements, It was my mistake for putting the link after WPF, but I meant MAUI

stupid of me, I was not getting the dictionnary itself, but creating a new one

@pf12345678910, I've just noticed that _resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary, anyway am going to post my answer

This is not good
_resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary
{
    Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyNamespace;component/wpf/styles/Styles.xaml")
};

The dictionary to use is in the user control resources
m_themeChanger = new ThemeChanger(Resources.MergedDictionaries);

from there on, just modify the color as the code provided by Mustafa
And Clemens is right, no need for fancy stuff
public void UpdateColors(string theme)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        m_themeChanger.UpdateColors(theme);
    });
}


General Themes Implementation

SharedClass.cs
public static class SharedClass
{
    public static void UpdateThemeColor(string themeName)
    {
        try
        {
            ResourceDictionary? mergedDictionaries = (ResourceDictionary)Application.Current.Resources;

            if (mergedDictionaries is not null)
            {
                mergedDictionaries["BackgroundColor"] = mergedDictionaries[themeName + "_" + "BackgroundColor"];
                mergedDictionaries["TextColor"] = mergedDictionaries[themeName + "_" + "TextColor"];

                mergedDictionaries["Main_1_Color"] = mergedDictionaries[themeName + "_" + "Main_1_Color"];
                mergedDictionaries["Main_2_Color"] = mergedDictionaries[themeName + "_" + "Main_2_Color"];
                mergedDictionaries["Main_3_Color"] = mergedDictionaries[themeName + "_" + "Main_3_Color"];

                mergedDictionaries["Main_Stroke_Color"] = mergedDictionaries[themeName + "_" + "Main_Stroke_Color"];
                mergedDictionaries["Main_Border_Color"] = mergedDictionaries[themeName + "_" + "Main_Border_Color"];

                mergedDictionaries["Main_Tab_item_Color"] = mergedDictionaries[themeName + "_" + "Main_Tab_item_Color"];
                mergedDictionaries["Main_Tab_item_Border_Color"] = mergedDictionaries[themeName + "_" + "Main_Tab_item_Border_Color"];

                mergedDictionaries["Main_Button_Color"] = mergedDictionaries[themeName + "_" + "Main_Button_Color"];
                mergedDictionaries["Main_Button_Border_Color"] = mergedDictionaries[themeName + "_" + "Main_Button_Border_Color"];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}

App.xaml
<Application.Resources>

    <!--#region For Theme Buttons -->
    <Style x:Key="Style_Ellipse" TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Orange" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="25"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--#region To-Be-Used on Controls to Support THEME -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundColor" Color="#99b4b6" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextColor">#68d8d6</SolidColorBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Main_1_Color">#07beb8</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Main_2_Color">#3dccc7</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Main_3_Color">#68d8d6</SolidColorBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Main_Stroke_Color">white</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Main_Border_Color">#8b8bcc</SolidColorBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Main_Tab_item_Color">#44a1a0</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Main_Tab_item_Border_Color">#0d5c63</SolidColorBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Main_Button_Color">#78cdd7</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Main_Button_Border_Color">#247b7b</SolidColorBrush>
    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--#region Theme 1 -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_1_BackgroundColor">#99b4b6</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_1_TextColor">#68d8d6</SolidColorBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_1_Main_1_Color">#07beb8</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_1_Main_2_Color">#3dccc7</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_1_Main_3_Color">#68d8d6</SolidColorBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_1_Main_Stroke_Color">white</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_1_Main_Border_Color">#8b8bcc</SolidColorBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_1_Main_Tab_item_Color">#44a1a0</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_1_Main_Tab_item_Border_Color">#0d5c63</SolidColorBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_1_Main_Button_Color">#78cdd7</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_1_Main_Button_Border_Color">#247b7b</SolidColorBrush>
    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--#region Theme 2 -->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_2_BackgroundColor">#e4e5f1</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_2_TextColor">#785947</SolidColorBrush>
 
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_2_Main_1_Color">#f9dbbd</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_2_Main_2_Color">#ffa5ab</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_2_Main_3_Color">#da627d</SolidColorBrush>
    
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_2_Main_Stroke_Color">#e7ddd3</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_2_Main_Border_Color">#f8f7f3</SolidColorBrush>


    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_2_Main_Tab_item_Border_Color">#722642</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_2_Main_Tab_item_Color">#a53860</SolidColorBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_2_Main_Button_Border_Color">#722642</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Theme_2_Main_Button_Color">#a53860</SolidColorBrush>
    <!--#endregion-->

</Application.Resources>


TESTING

MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow - TEST UI" Topmost="True" Height="450" Width="800" Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundColor}">

    <!--#region #IF MVVM VERSION -->
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <!--#endregion-->
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <!--#region Buttons | Change Theme -->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">

            <!--******************* #IF CODE-BEHIND Version *******************-->
            
            <!--#region Theme_1_Button -->
            <Button Margin="3" Click="Btn_UpdateTheme_Clicked" Tag="Theme_1" >
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Ellipse Fill="{DynamicResource Theme_1_Main_3_Color}" Style="{StaticResource Style_Ellipse}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
            <!--#endregion-->

            <!--#region Theme_2_Button -->
            <Button Margin="3" Click="Btn_UpdateTheme_Clicked" Tag="Theme_2">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Ellipse Fill="{DynamicResource Theme_2_Main_3_Color}" Style="{StaticResource Style_Ellipse}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
            <!--#endregion-->

            <!--******************* #IF MVVM Version *******************-->
            
            <!--#region Theme_1_Button -->
            <Button Margin="3" Command="{Binding UpdateThemeCommand}" CommandParameter="Theme_1" >
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Ellipse Fill="{DynamicResource Theme_1_Main_3_Color}" Style="{StaticResource Style_Ellipse}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
            <!--#endregion-->

            <!--#region Theme_2_Button -->
            <Button Margin="3" Command="{Binding UpdateThemeCommand}" CommandParameter="Theme_2">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Ellipse Fill="{DynamicResource Theme_2_Main_3_Color}" Style="{StaticResource Style_Ellipse}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
            <!--#endregion-->
        </StackPanel>
        <!--#endregion-->

        <!--#region MAIN Window TEST UI -->
        <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Main_Stroke_Color}"
                Background="{DynamicResource Main_Border_Color}"     
                BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="10" Height="100" Margin="10">
            <StackPanel>
                
                <Button BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Main_Button_Border_Color}" Background="{DynamicResource Main_Button_Color}" Content="My Button"/>
                <TextBlock Foreground="{DynamicResource TextColor}" Text="My TEXT" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"/>
            
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <!--#endregion-->

    </Grid>
</Window>


MainWindow.cs (Code-Behind Version)
namespace WpfApp2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Btn_UpdateTheme_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(sender is not null and Button button)
            {
                SharedClass.UpdateThemeColor(button.Tag.ToString());
            }     
        }
    }
}


MVVM Version
Install package CommunityToolkit.Mvvm from NuGet
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
namespace WpfApp2
{
    public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [RelayCommand]
        public void UpdateTheme(string ThemeName)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ThemeName))
            {
                SharedClass.UpdateThemeColor(ThemeName);
            }
        }
    }
}


thanks for the effort explaining with an example, as I already answered this question, it was a mistake I made earlier in the code

You're most welcome, I saw you fixed your code, however,  I posted my answer for the future users as a General Guide for themes implementation in WPF

Thanks Mustafa, you're the best !! when you got time, maybe you know how I could solve this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78651479/wpf-cannot-remove-padding-margin-around-datagrid-cells
